# Cakephp how can I give condition on Paginator setTemplate?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to give condition on paginator setTemplate method

I am actually trying to set a active css class in a sort url

```
$this->Paginator->setTemplates([
    'sort' => '<a class= "nav-link ml-auto" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a>',
    'sortAsc' => '<a class="nav-link active" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a>',
    'sortDesc' => '<a class="nav-link active" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a>'
]);
```

Here I want to give a condition or set a default active link , when user will visit products page. Example my all products sort by created desc.

So I am trying give a condition like

```
if (!$this->request->getQuery('sort')) and {{text}} == 'time' )
{
    return "nav-link active";
}
```

How can I give this condition ?

Comment: Simple order in query `->orderDesc('created')`

Comment: @Salines My question is how I will set default active css class in button. Here I have two sort button 1 is by time and another is by price. By default I want to set by time button active.